# What does " toward a smooth, flat lawn on the opposite side of the grounds to the forbidden forest" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

> At three-thirty that afternoon, Harry, Ron, and the other Gryffindors hurried down the front steps onto the grounds for their first flying lesson. It was a clear, breezy day, and the grass rippled under their feet as they marched down the sloping lawns **toward a smooth, flat lawn on the opposite side of the grounds to the forbidden forest**, whose trees were swaying darkly in the distance.
>   (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

The highlighted part seems to say there are the grounds between the flat lawn and the forbidden forest, and the lawn is on the opposite side of to the forbidden forest. Is this the right understanding?

Comment: What it means to me is they probably changed JKR's original ***towards*** to ***toward*** for the US edition. In fact, they [definitely changed it](http://home.comcast.net/~helenajole/Harry.html) (seven times, including this one in chapter 9 as noted there).

Comment: Please see my answer below. The accepted answer is not really correct.

Comment: @Daniel: Yes and no. I took the question to be about the spatial relationship between the specified lawn and the forest, rather than the meaning of what the school owns. The Forest's lying inside or outside the boundaries does not affect whether or not the specified lawn is across the grounds from it.

Comment: @JonathanGarber I agree that the question is about the spatial relationship between the lawn and the forrest; however, I don't think that it's right to say that the grounds are between them. That is not made clear by the sentence. The OP writes that he understands the sentence to mean that "there are the grounds..." which indicates to me that he misunderstands the meaning of the word "grounds."

Comment: FumbleFingers, that's a good point. I noticed that as well.

Comment: @Daniel: I think we have a semantic disagreement then. I would have no trouble referring to "most of the grounds" as "the grounds", and as a specific object, at least in the context of the given sentence. Regardless, I've edited my answer to be more specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is correct. The alignment would be like this:

> Flat Lawn |Rest of the grounds | Forbidden Forest

Or, in words: *"The Forbidden Forest is outside the grounds. On the opposite side of the grounds is the flat lawn."*

Rowling phrased it rather unfortunately, at least to my American understanding. I personally would have written something like:

> . . .toward a smooth, flat lawn located across the grounds from the Forbidden Forest.

Note that "opposite to" or "in opposition to" *is* grammatically correct, but as you have seen it does have potential for ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

No, this is incorrect.  "Grounds" is not a physical landscape feature. Grounds means essentially the same thing as "campus" (except it might not include the buildings of the campus). In other words, all of the land that is owned by Hogwarts are the grounds. The sentence does not make clear whether the features being discussed are on or off the grounds. I haven't read Harry Potter for a very long time, but I would guess that the Forbidden Forest is actually outside of the grounds of Hogwarts, while the grassy area to which they are walking is within the grounds.

The sentence means that the two things are on opposite ends of Hogwarts' grounds, regardless of whether they are inside or outside. For example, the Forbidden Forest might be on the west side of the campus (either inside or outside of the grounds) and the grassy area would be on the east side (either inside or outside).

Comment: The *grounds* would probably be understood to exclude the buildings, whereas the *campus* would include them. [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/english/ground?q=grounds#ground__7) — **grounds:** *an area of enclosed land surrounding a large house or other building:the house stands in seven acres of grounds; the university grounds.*

Comment: @PeterShor fair enough.